# Using LISTAGG in a pivoting task

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, listagg

I have a table (database.schema.table1) with the following data:

| transaction_id | state | transaction_type | date_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CA | Payment | 12/1/2022 01:00:00 |
| 1 | CA | Payment | 12/1/2022 02:00:00 |
| 1 | MA | Payment | 12/1/2022 01:00:00 |
| 2 | MA | Refund | 12/1/2022 01:00:00 |
| 3 | NY | Payment | 12/1/2022 01:00:00 |
| 4 | MA | Payment | 12/1/2022 03:00:00 |

I want my result set to look like this:

| transaction_id | transaction_type | CA | NY | MA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Payment | 12/1/2022 01:00:00, 12/1/2022 02:00:00 |  | 12/1/2022 01:00:00 |
| 2 | Refund |  | 12/1/2022 01:00:00 |  |
| 3 | Payment |  | 12/1/2022 01:00:00 |  |
| 4 | Payment | 12/1/2022 03:00 |  |  |

I have tried the following query but it doesn't seem to work in Snowflake for some reason (and have tried some variations of what I tried googling online):

```
SELECT *
FROM database.schema.table1 t1
PIVOT(LISTAGG(t1.time, '|') FOR t1.state IN ('CA', 'MA', 'NY')) AS p;
```

Is there any way I can try to use a `LISTAGG` in this pivot?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach using the cool function [ARRAY_AGG()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html).

[image]

```
SELECT   
  TRANSACTION_ID
, TRANSACTION_TYPE
, ARRAY_TO_STRING("'CA'",',') CA
, ARRAY_TO_STRING("'MA'",',') MA
, ARRAY_TO_STRING("'NY'",',') NY
FROM   
    T1
PIVOT (ARRAY_AGG(T1.DATE_TIMESTAMP) FOR T1.STATE IN ('CA','MA','NY'));
```

where T1 was lifted from Felipe's excellent answer.

```
with t1 as (
select transaction_id, state, transaction_type, date_timestamp
from (
    select split(value, '|') x, trim(x[0])  transaction_id, trim(x[1]) state, trim(x[2]) transaction_type, x[3]::string::timestamp date_timestamp
    from table(split_to_table(
    $$      1      |   CA   |     Payment      |   12/1/2022 01:00:00
            1      |   CA   |     Payment      |   12/1/2022 02:00:00
            1      |   MA   |     Payment      |   12/1/2022 01:00:00
            2      |   MA   |     Refund       |   12/1/2022 01:00:00
            3      |   NY   |     Payment      |   12/1/2022 01:00:00
            4      |   MA   |     Payment      |   12/1/2022 03:00:00$$, '\n'))
)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with an explicit pivot operation:

```
SELECT transaction_id, 
       transaction_type,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN state = 'CA' THEN date_timestamp END, ', ') AS CA,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN state = 'NY' THEn date_timestamp END, ', ') AS NY,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN state = 'MA' THEn date_timestamp END, ', ') AS MA
FROM tab
GROUP BY transaction_id,
         transaction_type
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to run the `listagg()` before the pivot - then the pivot will run as desired:

```sql
with data as (
    select transaction_id, state, transaction_type, date_timestamp
    from (
        select split(value, '|') x, trim(x[0])  transaction_id, trim(x[1]) state, trim(x[2]) transaction_type, x[3]::string::timestamp date_timestamp
        from table(split_to_table(
        $$      1      |   CA   |     Payment      |   12/1/2022 01:00:00
                1      |   CA   |     Payment      |   12/1/2022 02:00:00
                1      |   MA   |     Payment      |   12/1/2022 01:00:00
                2      |   MA   |     Refund       |   12/1/2022 01:00:00
                3      |   NY   |     Payment      |   12/1/2022 01:00:00
                4      |   MA   |     Payment      |   12/1/2022 03:00:00$$, '\n'))
    )
)

select *
from (
    select transaction_id, transaction_type, state, listagg(date_timestamp, ', ') arr
    from data
    group by 1, 2, 3
) t1
pivot(min(arr) for t1.state in ('CA', 'MA', 'NY')) as p
order by 1;

;
```