# Snowflake - PIVOT rows to get distinct/unique arrays

Tags: pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Inspired by [Adrian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73229184/5070879) I wonder if it is possible to use [PIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html) to produce combined and **unique** list of values.

Sidenote: `ARRAY_AGG` is not listed in the PIVOT's doc.

Sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test_data(studentid INT, grade TEXT, month TEXT /*columns*/)
AS SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1, 'A', 'JAN'),
    (1, 'A', 'JAN'),
    (2, 'C', 'JAN'),
    (2, 'D', 'JAN'),
    (2, 'D', 'JAN'),
    (1, 'B', 'FEB'),
    (1, 'B', 'FEB'),
    (2, 'F', 'FEB'),
    (2, 'E', 'FEB'),
    (1, 'B', 'MAR'),
    (1, 'B', 'MAR'),
    (2, 'A', 'MAR'),
    (2, 'B', 'MAR');
```

Using PIVOT:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_data
PIVOT (ARRAY_AGG(grade) FOR month IN ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR')) AS p;
```

Output:

| STUDENTID | 'JAN' | 'FEB' | 'MAR' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [ "A", "A" ] | [ "B", "B" ] | [ "B", "B" ] |
| 2 | [ "C", "D", "D" ] | [ "F", "E" ] | [ "A", "B" ] |

The desired output should not include duplicates inside arrays. Usage of `DISTINCT` keyword produces the following error:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_data
PIVOT (ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT grade) FOR month IN ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR')) AS p;
```

> Syntax error: unexpected 'DISTINCT'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it is possible to achieve it using [recently introduced function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2022-05.html#new-sql-functions)

> [ARRAY_UNQIUE_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_unique_agg.html):
>
> Returns an ARRAY that contains all of the distinct values from the specified column.

Code:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_data
PIVOT (ARRAY_UNIQUE_AGG(grade) FOR month IN ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR')) AS p;
```

Output:

| STUDENTID | 'JAN' | 'FEB' | 'MAR' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [ "A", ] | [ "B" ] | [ "B" ] |
| 2 | [ "C", "D",] | [ "F", "E" ] | [ "A", "B" ] |